# img TAG attribute in the first one is different than others I can't get the link? web scraping python

Tags: python, html, image, web-scraping, web

The code below is an example.

On the first img. You can see the class is (class_name) and the src= contains a link. But the rest of the img TAGS you will see the classes are different, and there is no src attribute there is data-src only.

So when I try to get the links, I am only able to get the links either for the first one or the rest of the links **only** if I change the ( get('src') to get('data-src') ).

Is there any way to get the links **only** as text?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'website.com'
soup = BeautifulSoup.get(url)

links = {
    '<img class="class_name" src="https://website1.png"/>',
    '<img class="class_name late" data-src="https://website2.png"/>',
    '<img class="class_name late" data-src="https://website3.png"/>',
}

for link in links:
    link.find('img', class_='class_name').get('src')
    print(link)
```

Thanks

I need the output like this:

```
https://website1.png
https://website2.png
https://website3.png
```

Comment: `link.find('img', class_='class_name').get('src') or link.find('img', class_='class_name').get('data-src')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply select all of the images, iterate over the `ResultSet` and check if an attribute is available to extract its value and print it or append it do a `list` or  `set` in case of avoiding duplicates.

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<img class="class_name" src="https://website1.png"/>
<img class="class_name late" data-src="https://website2.png"/>
<img class="class_name late" data-src="https://website3.png"/>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for link in soup.select('img.class_name'):
    if link.get('src'):
        print(link.get('src'))
    else:
        print(link.get('data-src'))
```

##### Output

```
https://website1.png
https://website2.png
https://website3.png
```